# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se repita el segundo elemento de una lista en una "lista de listas"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de hacer una lista de listas, pero al momento de realizar el append, el segundo elemento de esa lista se repite.

[image: Así es como luce al momento de ejecutar la lista de listas]

Anexo aquí mi código.

[image: prueba.py]

//// Código del generador de txt (Funcionando)

```
from random import randint 
class Negativos(Exception):
    pass
class Menores(Exception):
    pass
class Menores2(Exception):
    pass

print("\n")
while True:
    try:
        print("\n")
        d = int(input("\t\t\tIntroduce la cantidad de archivos a generar: "))
        print("\n")
        n = int(input("\t\t\tIntroduce la cantidad de numeros a generar: "))
        if d < 1 and n < 1:
            raise Negativos
        print("\n")
        wmin = int(input("\t\t\tIntroduce el peso minimo: "))        
        if wmin < 1:   
            raise Negativos
        print("\n")
        wmax = int(input("\t\t\tIntroduce el peso minimo: "))
        if wmax < wmin:   
            raise Menores
        print("\n")
        vmin = int(input("\t\t\tIntroduce el valor minimo: "))
        if vmin < 1:
            raise Negativos
        print("\n")
        vmax = int(input("\t\t\tIntroduce el valor maximo: "))
        if vmax < vmin:   
            raise Menores2 
        if d > 0 and n > 0:
            W  = int(0.50*(n)*((wmin+wmax)/2))
            for archivo in range(d):
                k = str(archivo+1)
                # print("\n")
                # print("\t\t    *** Archivo # " + k + " ***")
                # print("\t\t\t" + " i " + "Vi " +  "Wi")
                for i in range(n): 
                    vi = randint(vmin,vmax)
                    wi = randint(wmin,wmax)
                    # print("\t\t\t", i+1, vi, wi)
                    fichero = open(str(archivo+1) + ".txt",'a')
                    fichero.write(str(vi) + ",")
                    fichero.write(str(wi) + "\n")
                    fichero.close()
                fichero = open(str(archivo+1) + ".txt",'a')
                fichero.write(str(n)+ ","+ "\n")
                fichero.write(str(W)+ ",")
                del(fichero)
            print("\t\t **** Archivos creados satisfactoriamente **** ")
            break 
    except ValueError:
        print("\t\t\t Introduciste un caracter. Por favor introduce un numero entero.")
    except Negativos as na:
        print("\t\t\tNo se admiten valores menores a '1' ", na)
    except Menores as mens:
        print("\t\t\t El valor del peso maximo no puede ser menor al del peso minimo, ingrese un valor mayor a ",wmin, mens)
    except Menores2 as mens2:
        print("\t\t\t El valor del peso maximo no puede ser menor al del peso minimo, ingrese un valor mayor a ",vmin, mens2) </i>
```

///Código de Mochila.py

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

print("\n")
archivo = str(input("\t\t\tIntroduce el nombre del archivo: "))
file = np.genfromtxt(archivo + '.txt', delimiter =",", usecols=0) #Vi

#**********Obteniendo el peso de la mochila*****
labels1 = np.genfromtxt(archivo +".txt", delimiter=',', dtype="int")
W = np.genfromtxt(archivo+".txt", delimiter=',')[-1,0:1]
W= int(W)
print("\n")
print("\t\t\t Capacidad de la mochila:       ", W)
#*************************************************

#**********Obteniendo el numero de elementos*****
labels1 = np.genfromtxt(archivo +".txt", delimiter=',', dtype="int")
N = np.genfromtxt(archivo+".txt", delimiter=',')[-2,0:1]
N = int(N)
print("\t\t\t Cantidad de elementos posibles: ", N)
#*************************************************

#**********Obteniendo columna Vi*****
# labelsvi = np.genfromtxt(archivo +".txt", delimiter=',', usecols=0, dtype="str")[0:-2]
# for io in labelsvi:
#   vio = int(io)
#   # print(r)
#   # print(vio)  #*** Obtienes la columna Vi desordenada con numeros enteros

# #*************************************************

# #**********Obteniendo columna Wi*****
labelswi = np.genfromtxt(archivo +".txt", delimiter=',', usecols=1, dtype="str")[0:-2]
for wi1 in labelswi:
    f = int(wi1)
    # o = []
#   o.append(f)
#   o = list(o) #*** Obtienes la columna Wi con numeros enteros
# #     print(f) #** No se necesita ***
# #*************************************************


# #**********Ordenando la columna Vi*****
# ordenado1 = sorted(labelsvi, reverse=True) #Mayor a menor
# for i1 in ordenado1:
#   e = int(i1)
#   p = []
#   p.append(e)  #*** Obtienes la columna Vi ordenada con numeros enteros
    # print(e) ** No se necesita ***
# #*************************************************
l = []

labelsvi = np.genfromtxt(archivo +".txt", delimiter=',', usecols=0, dtype="str")[0:-2]
for io in labelsvi:
    vio = int(io)
    l.append(vio)
    labelswi = np.genfromtxt(archivo +".txt", delimiter=',', usecols=1, dtype="str")[0:-2]
    for wi1 in labelswi:
        f = int(wi1)
```

Comment: te recomiendo publicar tu código como texto ya que muchos no queremos tipear sino solo copiar el código.

Comment: Disculpa, no sabía como anexar el código. Pero ya esta publicado.

Comment: genial, pero en SO las respuestas deben publicarse no como edición de la pregunta sino en la sección de respuestas, asi que te invito a hacerlo y marcarlo como correcta, para mayor información revisa el [tour] :-)

Comment: Angel no se si se me está escapando algo, pero ¿Por qué no creas el array con las filas de primeras en vez de cargar columna a columna e iterar por cada una de ellas: `fa = np.genfromtxt(archivo +".txt", delimiter=',', usecols=(0,1), dtype="int")[0:-2]`, y si quieres una lista de listas (ahora creas una lista de tuplas por cierto) simplemente la creas con `l = fa.tolist()`?

Comment: Gracias por comentar nuevamente, lo tendré más presente en futuras publicaciones @eyllanesc.

Comment: Qué pasada, hombre! @FJSevilla, jamás se me pasó por la mente hacer eso, muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, finalmente hice lo que propusiste y fue más sencillo a la hora de ordenar por el indice del elemento. Saludos y nuevamente, gracias!